# How to display all files under folders in treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Iam trying to get all drives, folders, subfolders and files in treeview control using winforms. I have seen the following article.

http://codehill.com/2013/06/list-drives-and-folders-in-a-treeview-using-c/

but this only shows drives, folders and sub folders but not the files containing in these folders.

Please anyone help and guide that how can i view all these files under these folders in treeview, thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GetDrives
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //get a list of the drives
            string[] drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();

            foreach (string drive in drives)
            {
                DriveInfo di = new DriveInfo(drive);
                int driveImage;

                switch (di.DriveType)    //set the drive's icon
                {
                    case DriveType.CDRom:
                        driveImage = 3;
                        break;
                    case DriveType.Network:
                        driveImage = 6;
                        break;
                    case DriveType.NoRootDirectory:
                        driveImage = 8;
                        break;
                    case DriveType.Unknown:
                        driveImage = 8;
                        break;
                    default:
                        driveImage = 2;
                        break;
                }

                TreeNode node = new TreeNode(drive.Substring(0, 1), driveImage, driveImage);
                node.Tag = drive;

                if (di.IsReady == true)
                    node.Nodes.Add("...");

                dirsTreeView.Nodes.Add(node);
            }

        }

        private void dirsTreeView_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                if (e.Node.Nodes[0].Text == "..." && e.Node.Nodes[0].Tag == null)
                {
                    e.Node.Nodes.Clear();

                    //get the list of sub direcotires
                    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(e.Node.Tag.ToString());

                    foreach (string dir in dirs)
                    {
                        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
                        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(di.Name, 0, 1);

                        try
                        {
                            //keep the directory's full path in the tag for use later
                            node.Tag = dir;

                            //if the directory has sub directories add the place holder
                            if (di.GetDirectories().Count() > 0)
                                node.Nodes.Add(null, "...", 0, 0);

                            foreach (var file in di.GetFiles())
                            {
                                TreeNode n = new TreeNode(file.Name, 13, 13);
                                node.Nodes.Add(n);
                            }

                        }
                        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                        {
                            //display a locked folder icon
                            node.ImageIndex = 12;
                            node.SelectedImageIndex = 12;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "DirectoryLister",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            e.Node.Nodes.Add(node);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have now updated my code in application and using only one treeview, but the problem still exists.  You can see in image, in my C drive i have a file name "courses outline.html" and ab.txt which are not showing in application, which i need to see. Please see iamge below to easily understand my requirement.
[image: click on this image]

Comment: have you seen my answer? it works with only one treeview..

Comment: i've found the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code in the try block (from: [List Drives and Folders in a TreeView Using C#](http://codehill.com/2013/06/list-drives-and-folders-in-a-treeview-using-c/)) as following:

**EDIT:**

Added following code, because the files of the root-directory were ignored:

```
//add files of rootdirectory
DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(e.Node.Tag.ToString());
foreach (var file in rootDir.GetFiles())
{
    TreeNode n = new TreeNode(file.Name, 13, 13);
    e.Node.Nodes.Add(n);
}
```

Full class:

```
private void treeView1_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
    {
        if (e.Node.Nodes[0].Text == "..." && e.Node.Nodes[0].Tag == null)
        {
            e.Node.Nodes.Clear();

            //get the list of sub direcotires
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(e.Node.Tag.ToString());

            //add files of rootdirectory
            DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(e.Node.Tag.ToString());
            foreach (var file in rootDir.GetFiles())
            {
                TreeNode n = new TreeNode(file.Name, 13, 13);
                e.Node.Nodes.Add(n);
            }

            foreach (string dir in dirs)
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode(di.Name, 0, 1);

                try
                {
                    //keep the directory's full path in the tag for use later
                    node.Tag = dir;

                    //if the directory has sub directories add the place holder
                    if (di.GetDirectories().Count() > 0)
                        node.Nodes.Add(null, "...", 0, 0);

                    foreach (var file in di.GetFiles())
                    {
                        TreeNode n = new TreeNode(file.Name, 13, 13);
                        node.Nodes.Add(n);
                    }

                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    //display a locked folder icon
                    node.ImageIndex = 12;
                    node.SelectedImageIndex = 12;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "DirectoryLister",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                finally
                {
                    e.Node.Nodes.Add(node);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This look like following picture:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Schena, Iam near to my solution, I have updated my orignal post, Please see in EDIT. I need to reslove this issue as soon as possible, really thanks for your help.

Comment: Please share the solution, waiting for it impatiently, thanks.

Comment: It's arleady in my post

Comment: Ohh man! you people are changing the world siletly, keep it up. Love your soultion, thankyou v much :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the enumerate files method to get the name of each file inside a directory location.

```
string sourceDirectory = @"C:\current";
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory);

foreach (string file in files)
{
    // Do Something with file
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, The drive path like you mentioned @"C:\current" is basically a node name and i got it by this piece of code( treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath). When i click on this node + sign, i get empty space while i need files containing in these folders which are showing as treeview nodes, If you copy and paste code from the link i provided you can easily get my point, thanks.

Comment: Pelase see EDIT code in my orignal post, thanks.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i edit the code as you suggested but it is showing the files wrongly, for example if a file exists in "C:\myfolder\myfile.pdf" then it is showing in "c:\myfile.pdf". My requirement is to display files exactly in the same folder where it exists. If you can run my code then please insert two treeviews like treeview1 and treeview2 on canvas to verify the code, thanks and appreciate your help.